# Can't install RubyZip gem on OS X Lion with RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2, rubyzip

**TL;DR**:

```
$ gem install rubyzip 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rubyzip-0.9.4/README
```

---

And now in detail. I'm not sure which information is relevant, so I'm just gonna say it all.

1. I recently upgraded from OS X Snow Leopard to Lion (also upgraded Xcode to 4.2)
2. **Everything worked just fine for a while**
3. Today I decided to install some gems (RSpec, Cucumber), and I **started getting date format warnings** whenever I did anything with RubyGems
4. I decided to update RubyGems, from 1.3.6 (I'm not sure here) to current 1.8.11
5. The warning kept on popping up, so I **tried to remove the gemset** with `rvm gemset empty`, which also failed, because of some permission denied error (yes stupid me didn't write it down)
6. In result of that, I **reinstalled Ruby** via `rvm remove 1.9.2` and `rvm install 1.9.2` (I didn't forget to `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` after that.
7. I installed bundler `gem install bundle` and then tried to `bundle install` in my Rails 3.1.1 project, but it ends with error

   ```
   Installing rubyzip (0.9.4) 
   Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - /Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rubyzip-0.9.4/README
   An error occured while installing rubyzip (0.9.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install rubyzip -v '0.9.4'` succeeds before bundling.
   ```
8. `gem install rubyzip -v '0.9.4'` gives the above mentioned error
9. The README file says to download source and install from there via `ruby install.rb`, which also ends in error

   ```
   $ ruby install.rb 
   /Users/darth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:841:in `install': wrong number of arguments (4 for 3) (ArgumentError)
   from install.rb:21:in `block in <main>'
   from install.rb:18:in `each'
   from install.rb:18:in `<main>'
   ```
10. Even executing tests fro rubyzip ends up in bunch of errors

    ```
    $ rake test
    rake/gempackagetask is deprecated.  Use rubygems/package_task instead
    rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
    /Users/darth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby -C test alltests.rb
    <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- stdrubyexttest (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from alltests.rb:5:in `<main>'
    rake aborted!
    Command failed with status (1): [/Users/darth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/b...]

    Tasks: TOP => test
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    ```
11. ### **I'm out of ideas, what can I do?**

Comment: Can you double check the version of rubygems you've got installed, now that you've re-installed it? There was an update (several versions ago) that had a cert/permission error that looked similar to this, that caused issues installing gems (which should be fixed in the latest rubygems)

Comment: @Jeremy Actually now that I've checked, I have rubygems 1.8.10. I have no idea how I got to 1.8.11, but I managed to solve the whole thing by reinstalling rvm and all rubies. See the posted answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure what caused this, but I managed to fix it by doing the following.

Since reinstalling Ruby 1.9.2 didn't help, I decided to be even more drastical and went down to rvm. I found out that I had version 1.1.something installed, which is about 9 months old.

I tried to update, but it didn't help, so `rvm implode` did the trick. I even had to `sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm`, probably because I managed to mess up some gem installs by adding `sudo` to them.

After reinstalling `rvm` and reinstalling 1.9.2, it seems like everything is working fine now, even with Xcode 4.2.

Lesson learned, `rm -rf` & reinstall is better than trying to upgrade from a year old version :)

Comment: Glad to hear this is sorted. I'd very much recommend not installing rvm or any gems as root (install without sudo), this is the recommended way of installing.